# is there any methods like cookies in iphone

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone development. i need to store a buttontag value temporarily and use it in another view is there any method to do this pls help me

Comment: This question is unintelligible.

Comment: Can you be more clear about what exactly you're trying to do? Give us an example scenario or a use case for what you have in mind, and we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Safari for iPhone supports cookies as every other browsers does. If you refer to a real objective-c coded app you might have a look at the NSUserDefauls and their related documentation in the SDK. These allow you to easily store and retrieve simple data.

Just a quick example here:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:saveUsername forKey:@"saveUsername"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:tabIndex forKey:@"startupTab"];
```

Comment: Altough working, this seams most inappropriate if Jeyavel is really trying to pass a value from one viewController to another, which is what I understood.